# Javascript- associative array sorting

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I need to sort the values `miles` and `price` based on `perMile`.

```
objs[i] = [
    {
        miles : array[i].value1
    },  
    {
        price: array[i].value2
    },
    {
        perMile: array[i].value3
    }
];
```

I am new to JavaScript

Comment: Your data structure doesn't make sense. Why do you have an array of objects where each object has a different property? Why not just have one object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest

```
objs[i] = {
    miles : array[i].value1,
    price: array[i].value2,
    perMile: array[i].value3
};
```

Then you can sort the `objs` array by the `perMile` properties of the items like this (assuming they're numbers):

```
objs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.perMile - b.perMile;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can use a library in this instance, you should try Jlinq - http://hugoware.net/Projects/jlinq - It's a library that will allow you to query a Javascript object (associative array) using SQL-esque methods (SORT, SELECT, FROM, etc). The examples on the site will help you to get started. It's a great library, well doucmented, and very lightweight.

Comment: Mark it down, but at least suggest why... JLinq is a very good library.